# Ember CLI and Setting ApplicationAdapter as Custom RESTAdapter w/ Neo4J

Tags: ember.js, neo4j, ember-data, ember-cli

So I am trying to create a custom RESTAdapter connecting to a Neo4j Heroku App using Ember CLI and I can't seem to get it working properly. The code is as follows:

In adapters/application.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://hosthere.com',

    find: function(store, type, label) {
        console.log('finding nodes');
        var url = '%@label/%@/nodes'.fmt(this.host, label);
        return this.ajax(url, 'GET');
    }
});
```

In routes/suits.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('SUITS');
    }
});
```

In models/suit.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: 'DS.RESTAdapter'
});
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And when you go to the "suits" page, I get the following 2 errors:

> Error while processing route: suits.index No model was found for 'SUITS' Error: No model was found for 'SUITS' 
>   No model was found for 'SUITS' Error: No model was found for 'SUITS'

I have an idea it might be my DS.Store.extend({}) is in the wrong spot, but there isn't much documentation on Ember-CLI on where to put it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you find a model from the store, you need to use the name of the model. In your case, the model is just 'suit'. You need to change 'SUITS' to 'suit' in the suites route like so:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('suit');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I made this change and interestingly enough, it did a GET on the host I had in the REST adapter. But it is not running my own "find" method where I appended the URL to include labels/<name>/nodes. Is there a way to modify it to use my custom find method?

Comment: That I don't know. I'd recommend opening a new question specific to that issue so other people see it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I figured it out and will be posting my answer in a second but you definitely helped steer me in the right direction. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up figuring out on making it output correctly. After following Beerlington's suggestion of changing the "find('SUITS')" to "find('suit')", I ended up changing my RESTAdapter to a complete custom Adapter and also added a serializer where I overrided the primary key.

So adapters/application.js looks like:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
var ApplicationAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({
   host: 'http://thishost.com',
   headers: { ... },
   find: function(store, type, id) { ... },
   findAll: function(store, type, label) { ... },
   findQuery: function(){ ... },
   findMany: function(){ ... },
   createRecord: function(){ ... },
   updateRecord: function(){ ... },
   deleteRecord: function(){ ... }
});
export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

From app/serializers/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
   primaryKey: '_id"
});
```